# NVIC_Priority and main() priority on stm32

Tags: callback, program-entry-point, stm32

I'm using 3 PWM + USB (3 different TIM) to generate 3 80khz square waves and when they start to work near say 50khz i notice that the main loop is not executed (i have a blinking led of 1 sec).
USB has a priority of 0 while PWMs have 1 (could be changed). This is because the target wave freq is given through USB.

In the PWM callback, since the waves can accelerate or decelerate, i'm calling a function which elaborate at which value the next CCR/ARR should count in order to have a smooth acceleration.

My understanding is that the computational power required is starting to grow and the interrupts are a lot, filling in the available slots.

What i could do is to call the function above in the main loop by using a simple boolean variable that changes to true inside the PWM callback function and to false once the main called the funcion.

I'm afraid that this approach could lead to a not so perfect 70/100khz square wave for example (maybe 63khz or 95khz due to the main() computation time required).

So is there a way to give the main a sort of priority as well?
The main is basically checking if 5ms/10ms/50ms/1s have passed for example.

Comment: Which STM32 are you using? Why are you doing the PWM with interrupts? Why aren't you having the timer module do all that work for you? You can change some of the register values with the DMA. I've created sine waves with Timer1 using this method. I suspect I must be missing something but  creating 100k square waves in software seems bonkers to me. :)

Comment: I need to use interrupts because i need to count each square wave pulse.
Moreover i need the interrupts because if i have a 100khz target the wave should do 10-20-30-40-50-60-70-80-90-100Khz with a linear calibratable "acceleration" . This means i need to change CCR and ARR dinamically

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "count" each square wave. Are you really telling me that you are toggling the pin in software on each timer interrupt? Also, exactly how often are you changing the frequency? I think I'm still missing something.

Comment: No i'm not toggling the pin in the software, but i'm counting each pulse with HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback() and inside this callback i'm changing the CCR/ARR at each first square wave until i reach the desired frequency.

Comment: If I understand what HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback is, then this is called every single time a period has elapsed; running at 100kHz that is an interrupt going off every 10us which is crazy. If that is the case, you're overloading the processor. If you know how many pulses you want to output before changing the frequency, simply calculate how long that would take then set another timer interrupt in which you change your PWM frequency. You still haven't clearly explained what you're trying to do though, so there may be a better/neater way of doing this.

Comment: You might be able to do all your PWMs with one timer, not three. Timer 1 is pretty powerful.

Comment: That is indeed the case, the acceleration/deceleration and the occurrence counter of the square wave changes at each interrupt until the target is reached. At that moment the counter still counts the square wave occurences and the frequency is kept constant. The timer solution is somewhat good but since the square occurrences must be accurate (none can be lost) i'm not entirely sure if it is viable.

Comment: Is one TIM with 3 channels less demanding than 3 TIM each with 1 channel?

Comment: A timer will be accurate. It's running on the same crystal as the PWM ;) If you know how many pulses you want it's a relatively simple calculation to work out how many milliseconds will have elapsed. You could always have your time elapsed interrupt go off a few times before changing output frequency to increase granularity, but hugely cut down on time spent being interrupted. You might even be able to have a look-up table for the next timer values.

Comment: Can DMA help me here? I don't specifically need an interrupt after the frequency is kept constant but only when it is increasing, i just need an increment of an address at that point.

Comment: Possibly, yes, on the DMA front. I used DMA that was triggered at the end of each PWM period. It depends whether you could use the timer to trigger the DMA. I doubt that's possible though as I think your timer period for change of frequency timer would change depending on PWM timer if you're changing after a specific number of pulses. TBH if you're changing PWM frequency even every 5ms that's not such an overhead.

Comment: That is not clear, just to be sure we are on the same line.
if target is 100Khz what happens is:
    1. 100Hz Square wave for one pulse and counter=1
    2. 200Hz Square wave for one pulse and counter=2
    3. 400Hz Square wave for one pulse and counter=3
    4. xxxHz Square wave for one pulse and counter++
    xxx. 100Khz Square wave for indefinite time and counter++

so in the first case the interrupt is at 1/100hz, the second is 1/200hz after the first, the third is 1/400hz after the second and so on until the one which will be 1/100khz which is kept but only counter is incremented

Comment: Not sure. I don't have the code with me and it's seven years since I did this, but you can *definitely* change mark space ratio keeping frequency constant with the DMA. Whether you can also change its frequency I'm not sure. Maybe you could use a PWM mode that counts up and down and doesn't use CCR to decide when to change output pin state. The one remaining issue would then be to know when it's hit 100kHz and keep the PWM steady until you wanted to change back down. So, can you change PWM frequency by changing ARR, but always keep a 50% mark/space ratio. I bet you can.

Comment: Thought about this a bit overnight and did more reading; looks like there isn't a suitable DMA mode, *but*, I think you could change the prescaler value at the end of each pulse using DMA, keep ARR and CCR at the same value and once you have hit the requisite frequency, switch off DMA and keep it running at 100kHz until your desired time has elapsed (had required number of pules), then start again. That's minimal interrupts, you can run three PWMs off timer one. 

I'm not clear why you need three separate PWMs and whether they need to be out of phase with each other though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant there isn't a suitable PWM mode [where you can just change ARR].

Comment: They are used to generate 3 different waves. Changes only on PSC leads to a set of fixed frequencies while CRR and ARR gives you the full range.
By the way what was important to me was to be sure that 10us is indeed a performance wall for a 84Mhz micro and that it is impossibile to give to the main() a priority of some kind

Comment: Surely changing the prescaler would change the frequency of the outputs? As far as three separate waves are concerned, are they running at different frequencies at any point in time? 

I really think the whole main() priority thing is not what you should be concerned about. Working out how to do this with minimum processor intervention is key.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to give the main a sort of priority as well? The
>   main is basically checking if 5ms/10ms/50ms/1s have passed for
>   example.

No, main by definition runs at the lowest priority, idle. You can however, run stuff in the systick (or any other interrupt) to give regular tasks a higher priority. But if you're really out of time, changing priorities won't help.

> In the PWM callback, since the waves can accelerate or decelerate, i'm
>   calling a function which elaborate at which value the next CCR/ARR
>   should count in order to have a smooth acceleration.

I suggest you use the DMA for this instead.
At the start you compute, in advance, a section of the values. Then you use the DMA (timers have DMA requests) to write the new values to the timer, increment the source address, and let it run in hardware. The timer has the option to buffer the registers to only update on overflow to prevent glitches.
At half transfer interrupt you compute the next section of the circular source buffer. And on-and-on.

You can synchronize and connect many timers together. You just have to puzzle a bit.